# How to change properties of UITextField inside UISearchBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uitextfield, uisearchbar

Basically I am accessing this URL

```
UITextField * textField= self.searchBar.textField;
```

Let's just say the function .textField does get the textField. I have verified this several times.

```
textField.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth =true;
textField.minimumFontSize =10;
textField.enablesReturnKeyAutomatically =NO;
```

I followed with the code above.

Still the UITextField inside self.searchBar doesn't change font size when text is too long.

I wonder why.

Comment: Try subclassing `MySearchBar : UISearchBar` and customise in `layoutSubviews` method.

Comment: How exactly should I do so?

Answer (score 1):

Try to get your text field like this....

```
UITextField *textField = [searchbar valueForKey:@"_searchField"];

And then customize it according to you.

textField.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth =true;
textField.minimumFontSize =10;
textField.enablesReturnKeyAutomatically =NO;
```

Comment: I know how to get the textField. I can, for example, make it right align. However, I cannot make the font in the text field to autoadjust.

Answer (score 1):

You should try using `UIAppearance` instance method when you want to change some class instance which is contained in other class instance. (Looking for the view hierarchy is the work around).

```
[[UITextField appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] setTextColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
```

Here it is well explained in [documentation by Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try this code..This way you can change and manage properties of UITextField inside UISearchBar

```
for (UIView *searchBarSubview in [searchbar subviews])
{
    if ([searchBarSubview conformsToProtocol:@protocol(UITextInputTraits)])
    {
        @try
        {
            [(UITextField *)searchBarSubview setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];
             [[UITextField appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"jots" size:10]];

            [[UITextField appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth];

            [[UITextField appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] enablesReturnKeyAutomatically];

        }
        @catch (NSException * e)
        {
            // ignore exception
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps you..